# How do I close SalesQuotation Details Form in the background?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I have created some form in which it sended a few items to the sales lines in sales order detail form. What I need now is some logic to check if salesquotation detail form is open in the background then close it. Can anyone help.

Comment: Are you opening the SalesQuotationTable through code?

Comment: If you find the answer useful then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not best practice to close forms by code, the user should be in control.

But if you insist:

```
void close()
{
    if (formRun && !formRun.closed())
        formRun.close();
    super();
}
```

This closes a child form (if not already closed) when closing the current form.

Of course this requires you to open the child form by code as explained [here](http://dynamics-ax-live.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-open-form-by-code.html).

Comment: This does not check to see if the sales Quotation Table Form is open, This also assumes that the sales quotation table form was opened via code as well.

Comment: I disagree, it does check if it is open (not closed), and it is explicitly stated that you need to open the form by code. Read the answer again.